# Scanning First Line of .txt File to Determine Matrix Dimensions

Tags: c, eclipse

I need help with a homework assignment.  I am writing a program that reads two input files with numbers (.txt files).  These files will be matrices; however I don't know how to scan the first line of the file to determine the matrix dimensions.  I would greatly appreciate if anyone can help me, so that I can go on with the rest of my program.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please upload a relevant sample of what you have so far? I encourage you to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on asking [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have uploaded a bit of what I have.  The numbers in the txt file are: 3 3 new row 1 2 3 new row 4 5 6 new row 7 8 9.  The 3 3 in the beginning are suppose to be the dimensions of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix dimensions are stored as decimal integers, read them with this:

```
int rows, cols;
FILE *file = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");

if (file == NULL) {
    // error, cannot open the file
    return 1;
}

if (fscanf(file, "%d%d", &rows, &cols) != 2) {
    // error, cannot parse 2 integers
    return 2;
}
```

How you allocate the matrix and parse its contents depends on the type specified for the elements. You should seek help from a friend locally as you do not seem to have the required skills to complete this homework.

**EDIT**: in your code, you should define `i` as `int` to allow `EOF` detection in the classic read loop:

```
int i;
while ((i = fgetc(inputfileptr)) != EOF)
    printf("%c", i);
```

Comment: @SBrg: may I ask why you no longer accept this answer?